# Can I run filters before form-login redirection?

Tags: java, forms, servlets, servlet-filters

I have a Java webapp that uses form login and also contains filters.  I would like to use a filter to show a confirmation page that must be accepted before showing the login screen.  Is this possible?  It seems like the login stuff runs before all filters and servlets.

**Update:** my login page isn't implemented a filter; it's using the container-provided form login.

Comment: i removed my answer because of the wrong assumption about your implementation.

Comment: I looked into this awhile ago. It did not appear that you can do this.